# Isothermal process question from notes

Tags: thermodynamics, flow

i came across a question in my class notes where i need to find the heat exchanged.

air is flowing through a constant area duct. the velocity at section 1 is 80 m/s and at 2 is 40m/s. the air goes through a isothermal process inside the duct such that pressure changes from 100kpa to 200kpa. find heat exchange during the isothermal process.

I thought of q=c∆t. i do not see any solution to this problem. Should't ∆T=0 mean Q=0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Heat** doesn't necessarily mean *temperature change*.

The term *heat* is just a term for thermodynamic energy transfer (likewise, *work* is a term for mechanical energy transfer). What the energy, that is being transferred as heat, is converted into can be many different forms. It doesn't have to be thermal energy i.e. a temperature change. It could also be used for phase changes (melting), could be absorbed into chemical bonds etc.

Furthermore, your scenario might not be an isolated process. Even if the heat transfer you are dealing with indeed causes a temperature change, possibly another process causes cooling at the same time so that the temperature remains constant.

All in all, **isothermal processes** (processes for which the temperature remains constant) do not necessarily mean $Q=0$. The formula $Q=cm\Delta T$ that you show tells how much heat that is required for a specific temperature change, and if the temperature doesn't change then this amount is obviously zero, as you also point out. But there still might be other nonzero $Q$s that are converted into other types of energy or that are simply lost to the surroundings. To avoid this confusion, you might want to resymbolise that equation as:

$E_T=cm\Delta T$

Here you indicate in a general manner the amount of thermal energy $E_T$ that a specific temperatur change corresponds to rather than conflating it with heat $Q$. It doesn't necessarily have to be due to heat when a temperature change happens (you can reach that via mechanical work as well, e.g.), but it just often is which is why $Q$ is an often-used symbol.

To solve your specific task at hand I think I would go for the ideal-gas law that relates pressure, volume and temperature as well as Bernoulli's law that relates flow speed with volume.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes much more sense now. I don't understand why this wasn't explained to us. Also we don't consider the other Q's maybe because of the difficulty in accounting them..As for the problem I'll try again.

Comment: But I believe there should be a term included in textbooks like Q=cM∆T + "Qext" . Explaining this..

Comment: @LightoK I agree, this could often benefit from being explained better in regular textbooks. Just keep in mind that $$Q=mc\Delta T$$ is only one among many possible $Q$ contributions, namely the one that accounts for temperature change. Another typically used one is associated with phase changes (melting/freezing, evaporating/condensing) and is called *latent heat* with the formula: $$Q=mL$$